# Get PayPal Transaction ID and Captured Amount using Authorization ID

Tags: php, paypal

How to retrieve the PayPal Transaction ID (Capture ID) and captured amount using Authorization ID for the authorization that has already been completed using PayPal DoCapture API Operation.

Thanks in advance for your prompt response.